# how to get last seven dates data from database using current date

Tags: android, sql

I want to get last 7 dates of data from current date I am storing current date as string now how I will get last 7 dates of data using query? currently my code return my last 20 data from descending order now I want to show only last 7 days data so what will I do?

```
  public class JobSchema extends BackBaseActivity {

            List<JobSchmeModel> jobarr, missedarr;

               @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jobsschema);

             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());



            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(JobSchema.this);
                jobarr = db.getALLCompJobs();




      public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



               String CREATE_COMPLETED_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS
            + "(" + KEY_COMPID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TIMEJOB
            + " TEXT," + KEY_PICK + " TEXT," + KEY_DEST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FARE + " TEXT" + ")";




                    public List<JobSchmeModel> getALLCompJobs() {
    List<JobSchmeModel> compjobsList = new ArrayList<JobSchmeModel>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS+ " ORDER BY 
     "+KEY_COMPID+" DESC LIMIT 20";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            JobSchmeModel jobmodel = new JobSchmeModel();
            jobmodel.setTime(cursor.getString(1));
            jobmodel.setPick(cursor.getString(2));
            jobmodel.setDestination(cursor.getString(3));
            jobmodel.setFare(cursor.getString(4));
            // Adding contact to list
            compjobsList.add(jobmodel);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();

    return compjobsList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get Date before 7 days.

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(calender.getTimeInMillis());
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
String dateBefore7day =  postFormater.format(date);
```

Now your query will be

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " WHERE " + KEY_TIMEJOB + ">=" + dateBefore7day + " ORDER BY "+KEY_COMPID+" DESC";
```

**Edit:**

For get data between last 7 days to today and if you have future date data (data with date after current date) then you need to use this.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " WHERE " + KEY_TIMEJOB + ">=" + dateBefore7day + " AND " + KEY_TIMEJOB + "<=" + currentDate + " ORDER BY "+KEY_COMPID+" DESC";
```

Comment: It would be better to do it via query, this answer only addresses half of the problem.

Comment: ok now i have both days current date and 7 before 6 days  so how i wil lmakw query to get all records in between two dates?

Comment: just tell me how to make query to get if date <= current date

Comment: this query will work fine???
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " WHERE " + KEY_TIMEJOB + ">=" + dateBefore7day + " ORDER BY "+KEY_COMPID+" DESC";

Comment: why u use another check  + "<=" + currentDate + "?

if i only use in query day before 7 day it will ok??

Comment: first query will fail no result

Comment: It just because you need to change Datatype of `KEY_TIMEJOB` as `DATETIME` not `TEXT`.

Comment: SELECT  * FROM jobs WHERE timejob>=18/02/2014   15:20 AND timejob<=25/02/2014   15:20 ORDER BY _compid DESC

Comment: how to creatre field in database using date time?

Comment: Just Change `TEXT` to `DATETIME`. and Insert data methods will be same you can pass date as String to insert.